# DownloadFileAsync - not saving the file in folders

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

I am having an issue trying to get a file to save to a folder, I am using  DownloadFileAsync to get the file from a remote server, and attempting to save it in the following directory...

```
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Documents\\shadowforce\\ModLoader.zip"
```

However when I run the program and download, it seems to skip downloading it and says it is complete but with no file downloaded, I attempt to do it by removing "\ModLoader.zip" and it downloads the file and saves it as shadowforce.file

This is the line...

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.pwnage-gaming.com/Minecraft/ModLoader.zip"), "C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Documents\\shadowforce\\ModLoader.zip");
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Please add all relevant code. It's difficult to diagnose with what you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\`**My Documents**`\\shadowforce\\ModLoader.zip`

If this is a WinXP program, you should be using a My Documents folder.  If this is on Vista or newer, you would want to user the `C:\Users\Public`, not All Users.  So, I think it is throwing an exception because it cannot find the path.

Below is a piece of code from one of my programs that does in fact work.  It is XP/Vista agnostic, but in download it to the current user's documents folder.

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\somefile.ext");
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this. Although I used the same file reference in a VB project and it saved to the right location on W7